# Considering Dependency Injection, where should I build objects in nested logical layers?

Tags: oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Let's say I have something like this

- `Controller` uses `Service`.
- `Service` has `History`, `Source` and `HttpClient`.
- `Source` has `SourceRepository` and `id`.

  - `Source` is only useful for other objects after fetching information from `SourceRepository`.
- `History` has `HistoryRepository` and `Source`.

Below is a mixture of PHP + pseudocode (for the sake of simplicity) to ilustrate this scenario.

```php
public class Source
{
    ...
    public function __construct(InterfaceRepository $repository, int $id)
    {
        $this->data = $this->repository->findById($id);
    }
}

public class History
{
    ...
    public function __construct(InterfaceRepository $repository, InterfaceSource $source)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function hasHistory(): bool
    {
        return $this->repository->exists($this->source->data);
    }

    public function duplicateHistory()
    {
        ...
    }

}

public class Service
{
    ...
    public function __construct(InterfaceHistory $history, InterfaceSource $source, InterfaceHttpClient $httpClient)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function send()
    {
        if ($this->history->hasHistory()) {
            return $this->history->duplicateHistory();
        }

        return $this->sendNewRequest();
    }

    public function sendNewRequest()
    {
        $this->httpClient->postRequest($this->source->data);
    }
}

public class Controller
{
    public function doSomething(int $id)
    {
        $sourceRepository = new SourceRepository();
        $source = new Source($sourceRepository, $id);

        $historyRepository = new HistoryRepository();
        $history = new History($historyRepository, $source);

        $httpClient = new Guzzle();

        $service = new Service($history, $source, $httpClient);
        $service->send();
    }
}
```

Now I have some questions regarding Dependency Injection:

- Should all object building really stay in the highest level, in this case the `Controller`?

  - Or are there cases where **some** of the object building is in the middle layers?
- If I was to use a Dependency Injection Container, I think it wouldn't be able to instantiate `Source` because of `id`. How should I solve this?

Comment: Object graphs should be built in the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), not in the UI layer.

Comment: @Steven I didn't know about Composition Root, and that link you passed me is simply awesome! It made the whole situation crystal clear for me, thank you very much! I'll soon write an answer with all I learned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading more about Dependency Injection, Inversion of Control and [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) (quite awesome read by the way, suggested by @Steven), I understood what has to be done in my case.

So regarding my questions:

> Should all object building really stay in the highest level, in this case the Controller?

The part about *highest level* is correct, the rest isn't. The best place to do the *object building*, also called *object graph* is in the **Composition Root**, which is very close to the entrypoint of the application and/or specific route.

Composition Root is a logical layer and it's only responsibility is composing the object graph. It may be a separate class and/or function. Although it may be in the same file as another thing, it is still a separate layer. (Read [this link](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) again).

So in my case, what I'll do is before I get to the controller, I'll create a separate *Composition* class that will create everything necessary and inject only the `Service` to the `Controller`, so it can call `$service->send()`.

---

> If I was to use a Dependency Injection Container, I think it wouldn't be able to instantiate Source because of id. How should I solve this?

Incorrect. Dependency Injection Containers do have a way to instantiate classes with dynamic parameters such as scalar values or other.